# Benchmark Framework C++

Tags: c++, frameworks, benchmarking

There are any good benchmark framework for C++?

I know Hayai and Celero, but I wonder if there is a better tool available.

Anyone recommends a benchmark framework for C++?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question today and the only C++ benchmark frameworks I could find were the ones you mentioned: [Celero](https://github.com/DigitalInBlue/Celero) and [hayai](https://github.com/nickbruun/hayai).

I'll try `Celero` first, because it has an option to save the benchmark results in XML format, whereas `hayai` apparently can only print benchmark results to the console.

Comment: Hi Chris. I'm using Hayai and I really liked it, because it's very similar with google test, which is the test framework I'm using.